# Is there a way to run multiple concurrent Django apps (different settings, same code) in one process?

Tags: django

Basically this would be a situation where I'd want to run the same Django codebase, but use different settings for different incoming domains. For example, `foo.bar` might use the `settings/foo_bar.py` settings file, with a different database, etc. I'd like to have one process that, at runtime, "spins up" instances. Eg

```
def find_django_app(wsgi_request):
    settings_file = ...
    django.use_settings(settings_file)   # Does this exist?
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    return WSGIHandler()
```

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants, it may help solve the problem you're looking for. From your question, I can't think of a way to serve different `settings.py` files. But in multi-tenant architecture, usually you're using shared infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks, @Hayden. I actually did see django-tenants, but unfortunately that's not a level of isolation I'm really after. They need entirely separate settings, since some settings will be per-tenant.